# Crystal Report with Multiple Tables - Empty or Cartesian Product

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports, ms-access-2007

I know this has been asked before..sort of. And that's why I'm posting. Basically I'm building a report in Crystal that relies, to keep this simple, at least 3 tables.

Table A is inner joined to table B by a unique ID. Table B has a child table that may or may not have data related to this unqiue ID.

As a general example table A is a customer table, table B is a product table and the child table is contains the product number. All customers have a product, but not all customers have product number in the child table. I hope I've explained that simply enough.

My issue is sort of between Crytal and Access and how to query this. When I'm writing behind something in VB it's easy enough to write and execute a query and display the result in the desired manner. However I can't seem to get my query straight... I either end up with a report with cartesian product as the resultset, which displays ok...except that even with the few records I have ends up being about 30k pages..or I end up with a blank dataset because the child table does not have corrisponding data to B.

Using outter joins I've managed to get my results within some amount of reason but not acceptable to a real world report. I'm sure this issue has come up but I can't seem to find any suitable answers and to be honest I'm not even sure what questions to ask being a Crystal n00b.

What I'm really after is the data from Table A, the data from Table B and children tables. While they are logically linked and can be linked with the ID field, it isn't necessary I don't think because I am taking a parameter value for the report of the ID field. And once the tables are filtered, no other action needs to be taken except to dump them back on the report.

So can anybody point me in the right direction? Can I set up individual datasoruces (unrelated) based perhaps in a seperate section? Should I build a tree of queries and logic in my DB to get what I need out? I've been racking my brain and can't seem to find the right solution, any and all advice is apreciated and if I can clarify anything or answer any questions I will.

Thanks in advance.

As per requested below:

```
Section1

ID fname lname 
01 john smith 
Section2

ID notifiedDate notifiedTime 
01 10/10/2012   12:35PM 

S2childAdmin 
ID noteName 
01 jane doe
```

This data is logically related and can be related in the DB. However it is not necessary as long as the ID parameter is passed to each table. Querying Section1 inner joined with Section2 works fine. But any other arrangements result in more rows than required and I end up with a report many times duplicated. What I really need is something like Section1 joined with Section2 and S2childAdmin as a freely availble table. Otherwise it multiplies my data or results in a null recordset (because it can return 0 rows)

Comment: No, I've not been successful on that front either. I just can't figure out a way to link the tables so that I don't get a cartesian product and still have independant access to the table data. The children table actually will populate their related fields on the report

Comment: In that case, let's see can we get you a query which works correctly in Access.  Leave Crystal out of the equation for the moment.  Show us brief samples of the relevant columns from your tables and the result set you want based on that sample data.

Comment: @HansUp let me work something out. My DB is pretty exstensive. I'll get back to you soon

Comment: I'll try to consense this best as possible. I have in my DB Section1, Section2, and S2childAdmin. Section1 is the base starting place Section2 builds on it (next step in form) and S2childAdmin contains selections based of a multi select listbox of Section2. It can have 0 to N relations to Section2. I'll add a sample below.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications, Tyler.  I misunderstood the nature of your question; this is not about fixing an Access query to return the results you want.  What you want is not possible in an Access query.  If this were an Access application, you could present a join of the first 2 tables in a main form, and the "freely available table" in a subform.  Or a report and subreport.  I don't know what features Crystal offers.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should help point you in the right direction, though it has been 5 years or so since I did heavy Crystal Reports work.

One option might be to join everything using Outer Joins like you stated you were, then use a Crystal Report 'group' on the Table A ID, with a group based upon Table B ID inside of that.  So you would, in the actual 'Detail' area put your table C details if there were any, and then use the Group header/footer for Table A and Table B to show data specific to those objects.

Another possible solution that may fall short of your requirements but might get you thinking in another way, is to create your main report and in it, display the fields from table A.  Then below those fields include a sub-report and pass in the unique ID from Table A.  You will then have a query inside of the subreport that finds all of the Table B records with that Table A.ID value and displays their details.

At this point you run into a weakness of Crystal Reports (at least as of the last version I used) in that you cannot have a subreport inside of a subreport.

Comment: What little I've read about groups, a similar thought did cross my mind, but I'm not sure it would work well with the flow of the form. And that the part that I would also need to break out would contain some 10 groups that were entered using a multi select list box. If that gives you an idea of the layout of things. Subreports screams at me the way to go execpt again the layout of the report and the need for so many of them. I do like where your leading me though

Comment: If your structure is more flat / 2 tier.. like you have a top-level object and it has 1 to n different types of children objects... But those children do not have children, you'll want to look at subreports for certain.  The groups CAN be very flexible but I think you may have lost me now with the layout of the report.  If you have any sort of screenshot, could do a hand-sketch what you think you want and take a pic, whatever could help, I'd be glad to continue discussing this.

Comment: The structure is pretty basic but kind of large. I have Section1>Section2>Section3>Section4. Where each table builds on the data of the previous to obtain a full form. That works just fine. The issue is that I have fields whos data is contained in children tables, I can't seem to include this in any way without ending up with an incorrect result or completly redesigning the form to allow for subreports. I'll try to get you a screen, how might I go about uploading here? I'm not too familiar with this posting system.

Comment: You'll have to forgive me, a basic misunderstanding of the nature of sub-reports led me to say that. I don't know why but I was under the impression that it would be a more linear object design wise. But it turns out not to be the case after some experimentation. I do however need to find a way to either pass the desired parameter down through the report/sub-report structure. Do you have any suggestions? Without a crystal prompt of course..